# Search files having more than one strings in different lines Textpad or Notepad

Tags: regex, string, search, find, textpad

How can I search with/without using regex to find all the files in a directory having two or three words , like I want to search apple and ornages 
I tried this :

```
in the Find what -> apple.*oranges
```

also using reg ex

```
in the Find what -> ^(apple  &  oranges) also ^(apple  &&  oranges)
```

but not able to find any though there are files containing both.
OR rule also didnt work.

```
Here is an example on Notepad++ ,
tried both apple.*oranges as well as ^(apple  &&  oranges)
```

[image]

Comment: You need `apple.*oranges` as *regex*, but you say it does not work. Strange.

Comment: `(?=apple)(?=oranges)` may works

Answer (score 0):

Are your match terms over multiple lines?

If so it doesn't look like Textpad supports multiline regular expression matches which would leave you with two options.

1. Do a replace on all new line characters with a known string (e.g. [[NEWLINE]]) before the match, perform the match and then revert the replace
2. Find another piece of software that supports multiline regular expression matches ([Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) does)

Edit - Regex to use is `apples.*oranges`

This matches the string `apples` followed by any character (optional) and then followed by `oranges` and checking the option for `.` to match a new line means that the search with work over multiple lines.

This will also match applesoranges as the `*` means 0 or more matches, you can change the `*` to a `+` if you need at least one character between the words.

Comment: @Raulp I have added an edit with the regular expression to use, also make you you check the `. matches newline` option